# Dialogflow does not recognize a name from Training phrase

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, dialogflow-es

For some reason Dialogflow does not recognize the name which exists in Training phrase.
On the example i am sending "My name is Ashvin" and response should be. 
"What is your last name ?

Also i tried to make dialogflow to remember this name but its still does not want to recognize it.

[image]"

This is From Training screen:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an issue with Non-English/Non-American names with Dialogflow. Only the names put in the `@sys.given-name` DB by Dialogflow are recognised as of now. So most of the English names are getting recognised as well as some of the Non-English names (common in the USA) are captured via `@sys.given-name`.

If you have a limited set of names to recognise, you can put those names in a composite/enum Entity, then it will be recognised by the agent. Otherwise, use `@sys.any` and in the webhook, come up with some logic to approximate on to the name provided by the user and ask for confirmation once captured.

Composite Entity
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to make a composite entity like in the picture below. That way you can train it for the Indian names as well.

Check "**allowed automated expansion**" as well so that it can predict the names which are not in the list.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: dear downvoter, please comment as well why have you chosen to downvote the answer. so that i can learn.